# Is there a way to add new tags to a bunch of questions

Tags: feature-request, tags

On Stack Overflow, when you search for "ceres-solver", you find (today) [13 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ceres-solver). Almost all related to [Google ceres-solver](http://ceres-solver.org/). When I posted a new question on this library earlier today, I created the new tag "ceres-solver", fine.

Then, I started adding the tag to the few first questions of the search result. But I'm wondering if there could be a way to add a new tag to a bunch of questions at once, rather than having to edit them all one by one....doing so is a real pain, and it would really make sense to add the tag to all those posts...

Comment: What deterministic criteria are you using to decide whether a question should have a tag added?

Comment: The search does a pre-filter, then, you would need to pick them up one by one. On mast cases, `ceres solver` appears in the title, so it's easy to figure out it's about it. I'd like to have the ability to select many questions and then add the tag to all of them.